# How to download the latest release from github and extract the zip in a folder using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, github, unzip

I want to write a bash script to download the latest release from a github repo and extract the downloaded zip into a particular directory.

From [this gist](https://gist.github.com/steinwaywhw/a4cd19cda655b8249d908261a62687f8) I am able to download the zip file. The shell script looks like this.

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kgns/weapons/releases/latest \
| grep browser_download_url \
| cut -d : -f 2,3 \
| tr -d \" \
| wget -qi -
```

This downloads the zip file of the latest release from the repo. Now, I want to extract the contents of the zip file into `some/other/dir/`, replacing the current files that are there from the older version. How do I do this without knowing the name of the downloaded zip file, since that changes with every version?

Finally, I also want to clean up by deleting the zip file that I downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reformatted what you created a bit,
replaced cut and tr with a single sed to achieve about the same result.
The output from those then left in "$file", for your convenience...

```
$ file="$(
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/kgns/weapons/releases/latest \
| grep browser_download_url \
| sed -re 's/.*: "([^"]+)".*/\1/' \
)"

$ echo ${file##*/}
weapons-v1.7.5.zip
```

**reference:**
$ man bash
... With `man bash` displayed, type a single `/` to start search ( `q` to quit, `h` for help).
Search for
`Parameter Expansion` and `Command Substitution` (keep the CASE for those) to get explanations of what I have done.

---

More info on bash scripting:

`The Linux Documentation Project` https://www.tldp.org -> Bash guides